# app crashing on loading Google maps in FragmentActivity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

- To fetch current location on google maps i am uisng this code.
- This is showing me an error in LayoutInflater(please see Logcate).
- I am using fragment to show maps.
- I am using FragmentActivity instead of AppCompat Activity
- please give me some proper solution
- See logcate to check more errors in my code.

> xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/google_map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    Location currentLocation;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private static final int RequestCode=101;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fusedLocationProviderClient= LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        fethcLastLocation();
    }

    private void fethcLastLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},RequestCode);
            return;

        }

        Task<Location> task=fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location!=null){
                    currentLocation=location;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),currentLocation.getLongitude()+""+currentLocation.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment= (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);
                    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(MainActivity.this);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        LatLng latLng=new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(),currentLocation.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions=new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("You are here");
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,5));
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case RequestCode:
                if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    fethcLastLocation();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

> logcat

```
2019-10-08 09:35:30.310 7261-7261/com.example.mymaps E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:498)
        at com.android.internal.policy.HwPhoneWindow.setContentView(HwPhoneWindow.java:342)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2941)
        at com.example.mymaps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7458)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7448)
```

Comment: Can your add your API key in your manifest file?

Comment: Please post your manifest and build.gradle files. And can you confirm that you're using a valid API key? See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key